# git issue when there are multiple remotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, bitbucket

I am facing a very silly scenario.

I had worked a rails app few months back and now suddenly I have to make a little push to heroku by pulling some code from bitbucket repo.

This project has got 3 remotes. I mean when I run `git remote -v` below is what I am getting.

```
1bitbucket  ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/project.git (fetch)
1bitbucket  ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/project.git (push)
bitbucket   ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user1/project.git (fetch)
bitbucket   ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user1/project.git (push)
origin  git@heroku.com:project.git (fetch)
origin  git@heroku.com:project.git (push)
```

Now when I am doing `git pull`, It says Already up to date, so I tried with all other remotes and ran `git pull 1bitbucket` It pulled something.

But when I do rails s, the updated scenario doesn't come to my projects.

I am not sure what's wrong here. Has someone else face similar issue.

Please help.

Comment: Did you check git log? Do you find your commits listed?

Comment: I did not do any commit, someone else has pushed something and that's been listed there

Comment: Is it more of a js or rails app?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple alternatives to it but I would simply fetch all heads using

`git fetch --all`

and to be very specific to the particular origin

`git pull 1bitbucket <local branch>:<remote branch>`

Comment: I am sorry but didn't get you